# How can I conditionally disable the routerLink attribute?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my Angular 2 application I'm trying to disable a routerLink without any success. I've tried to handle the click event on the `click` event (with `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`) but it doesn't work.

How can I disable a routerLink?

Comment: This is such a massive waste of thousands and thousands of hours trying to find a solution that could be solved with about 5 lines of code in Angular :-( Could be as simple as `[routerLinkClickEnabled]="false"` and done!

Comment: @Simon_Weaver: Could you please provide a docu link for `[routerLinkClickEnabled]`? My searches are unsuccessful.

Comment: @MichaelD  this was a suggestion of what they *could* do to fix the problem and not something that actually exists. sorry I wasn't clearer! Hopefully now Angular 9 is out they'll be able to loop back on certain common issues like this one.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver: I overlooked the '_could be_' phrase in your original comment. All clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Disable `pointer-events` on the element via CSS:

```ts
<a [routerlink]="xxx" [class.disabled]="disabled ? true : null">Link</a>

a.disabled {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

See also [Angular2, what is the correct way to disable an anchor element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985112/angular2-what-is-the-correct-way-to-disable-an-anchor-element)

or

```ts
<a *ngIf="isEnabled" [routerlink]="xxx">Link</a>
<div *ngIf="!isEnabled">not a link</div>
```

or to easily reuse the disabled link template

```ts
<ng-template #disabledLink>
  <div *ngIf="!isEnabled">not a link</div>
</ng-template>
<a *ngIf="isEnabled; else disabledLink" [routerLink]="xxx">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I'm using bootstrap to add style to the navbar. Your solution removes the `not-allowed` cursor style when the link is disabled. I had to add it separately.

Comment: The `cursor` line can be omitted entirely, it's just the visual cue that the link is disabled. I bootstrap sets that already, use this setting instead.

Comment: Doesn't work for internet explorer and Edge - it's still clickable

Comment: You can use `*ngIf` to show alternative content instead of trying to make the `<a [routerLink]` to not behave like a link.

Comment: @user3292624 still, is IE considered a browser?

Comment: In a wider sense of the word, I guess so :D

Comment: Also useful if you want to disable the current active route: use routerLinkActive. Add pointer-events: none of the active class.

Comment: Do not work. If router link is empty: it redirects to default route. (angular 8)

Comment: @DamienC This answer does not say that an empty routerLink would solve the issue. Perhaps I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer . to manage conditional link, finally, I manage to do it only in controller. Unable to do it directly in template.
But in a architecture point of view, it's a better way to code it

Comment: If you use the second example and are using routerLinkActive on an ancestor element, you will find that the *ngIf will block the [routerLink] from being seen and thus routerLinkActive will fail to work as intended.  To work around this, just add an empty anchor element.

```
<li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
  <a [routerLink]="/some/where" *ngIf="foo">
    Link
  </a>
  <span *ngIf="!foo">
    Link
  </span>
  <a [routerLink]="/some/where" style="display:none"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Using `pointer-events: none;` on an `<a>` tag does not prevent users from using a keyboard to focus on and click the element.

Answer (score 122):

## Angular 13 and above

`[routerLink]="null"` (and `undefined`) is now officially used to disable the `routerLink`.
(see [Docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#properties))

So this is enough:

```html
<a [routerLink]="linkEnabled ? 'path' : null">Link</a>
```

## Angular 12 and below

`[routerLink]="null"` (and `undefined`) is treated as a shorthand for an empty array of commands. So it makes the `routerLink` to link to the current/active route. This behavior allows us to abuse the `routerLinkActive` directive for our purpose:

**Template:**

```html
<a [routerLink]="linkEnabled ? 'path' : null"
   [routerLinkActive]="linkEnabled ? 'is_active' : 'is_disabled'">Link</a>
```

**Optional CSS:**

```css
.is_disabled {
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.is_active {
    // your style for active router link
}
```

**Live demo (Angular 10):**
[See demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qkjohr?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Detailed Description:**

When `linkEnabled` returns `false`, `null` will make `routerLink` to link to the current/active route.

If `routerLink` links to the active route, the class which is specified in `routerLinkActive` will be applied. That will be `is_disabled` in this case.

There we can specify, how the disabled routerLink should appear.

`routerLink` to the active route won't trigger a navigation event.

Comment: Regarding the Angular 13 change, I'm very disappointed that it doesn't let you use an `href` when the `routerLink` is null. I have a case where I use the same component both in the main app and as a web component (Angular Elements) on other sites, so sometimes it should use routing and sometimes it should be a true URL.  

But if there is a `routerLink` at all, `href` just doesn't work.  E.g. `<a [routerLink]="!useHref ? '/account' : null" [href]="useHref ? 'mysite.com/account' : null">Account</a>`.  

I know I can use two separate links but that's going to be duplicate maintenance.

Answer (score 7):

All the top answer are workaround.

The best way is something you can find in this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/45323200/3241192 by @taras-d

> Another way to disable routerLink - replace onClick method.
>
> To do this you have to create directive:
>
> ```
> import { Directive, Input, Optional } from '@angular/core';
> import { RouterLink, RouterLinkWithHref } from '@angular/router';
>
> @Directive({
>     selector: '[routerLink][disableLink]'
> })
> export class DisableLinkDirective {
>
>     @Input() disableLink: boolean;
>
>     constructor(
>         // Inject routerLink
>         @Optional() routerLink: RouterLink,
>         @Optional() routerLinkWithHref: RouterLinkWithHref
>     ) {
>
>         const link =  routerLink || routerLinkWithHref;
>
>         // Save original method
>         const onClick = link.onClick;
>
>         // Replace method
>         link.onClick = (...args) => {
>             if (this.disableLink) {
>                 return routerLinkWithHref? false: true;
>             } else {
>                 return onClick.apply(link, args);
>             }
>         };
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> Usage:
>
> `<a routerLink="/search" [disableLink]="!isLogged">Search</a>`

Answer (score 6):

I've just had some success with a similar issue: having an array of nav links in an ngFor, some required [routerLink], while others required (click) - my issue was that all links relied on [routerLink] for [routerLinkActive], so I had to stop routerLink, without touching it's value.

```
`<a [routerLink]="item.link" routerLinkActive="isActive">
    <span (click)="item.click ? item.click($event) : void>
</a>`
```

with:

```
`click: ($event) => {
    $event.stopPropagation(); // Only seems to
    $event.preventDefault(); // work with both
    // Custom onClick logic
}`
```

As the span is inside, you can be sure the cancelling of the event happens before it bubbles up to [routerLink], while routerLinkActive will still apply.

Comment: You'd better add the click to the anchor. What if the user clicks inside the anchor but outise the span? (E.g. the anchor has padding.)

Answer (score 4):

Disabling `pointer-events` on **any** html tag:

```
<div [routerLink]="['/home', { foo: bar }]"
     [ngStyle]="{'pointer-events': myLinkEnabled ? 'none' : null}">
     Click me
</div>
```

`'none'` resolves to disabling `pointer-events`, that is, disabling the link.

`null` resolves to ignore the style.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Angular doesn't seem to have a **null** value support for the **routerLink**.

However, this works for me. An example of my menu implementation:

```html
<div *ngFor="let category of categories" [routerLink]="category.subcategories ? [] : [category.link]" (click)="toggleSubcategories(category)">
```

Simply put, if a category has any subcategories, don't redirect, but open the subcategories.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Empty array doesn't give any console errors e.g.  [routerLink]="exists ? ['/go']: []"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let childitem of menuitem.MenuRoutes">
<a [routerLink]="menuitem.IsMain ? [childitem.Route] : []"><a>
</>
```

Answer (score 1):

My case was to use routerLink, sometimes use click to open modal, and internal logic of route URL if we don't provide routerLink URL. So for click, I had to delete routerLink.

```
[routerLink]="disableRouterLink ? null : (btnRouterLink || pathCondition)"
```

in my case, `null` deletes routerLink attribute, and I can use `(click)` event properly.

P.S.  empty array `[]` provided in answers abowe doesn't remove attribute routerlink from the element.