# is there any alternative for ng-disabled in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am using angular2  for development and was wondering if there is any alternative for `ng-disabled` in angular2.

For ex.
below code is in angularJS:

```
<button ng-disabled="!nextLibAvailable" ng-click="showNext('library')" class=" btn btn-info btn-xs" title="Next Lib >> {{libraries.name}}">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw"></i>
</button>
```

Just wanted to know How can I achieve this functionality?
any inputs?

Comment: [disabled]="!nextLibAvailable" try this might help

Answer (score 305, accepted):

To set the `disabled` property to `true` or `false` use

```
<button [disabled]="!nextLibAvailable" (click)="showNext('library')" class=" btn btn-info btn-xs" title="Next Lib"> {{libraries.name}}">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Only works on `<button>,` (is that true?) , which is reasonable. Else get the error message (i.e. when try to bind to an `<a>`) ` Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'a' `

Comment: It works on every element that has a `disabled` property. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431188/angular

Comment: The disabled attribute is supported by <button>, <command>, <fieldset>, <keygen>, <optgroup>, <option>, <select>, <textarea> and <input>.

Answer (score 78):

```
[attr.disabled]="valid == true ? true : null"
```

You have to use `null` to remove attr from html element.

Comment: For angular > 2.x this is the correct way using [attr.disabled]

Comment: `attr.` is only required when the element doesn't have a `disabled` property. For elements like buttons and input elements `attr.` is redundant.  For elements that don't have a `disabled` property a binding to `attr.disabled` is only meaningful if you address it by CSS to make it look like disabled (mouse pointer, gray colors, ...)

Comment: Yes, this is best way when some of element doesn't have disabled property default.

Comment: You can see a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658800/how-to-bind-dynamic-data-to-aria-label) - it works with this attribute in your components HTML  `[attr.aria-disabled]="myPropReflectingIfDisabled"`. It will add an attribute `aria-disabled="true"` if `myPropReflectingIfDisabled` is `true`.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a solution am using with anular 6.

```
[readonly]="DateRelatedObject.bool_DatesEdit ? true : false"
```

plus above given answer

```
[attr.disabled]="valid == true ? true : null"
```

did't work for me plus be aware of using null cause it's expecting bool.

Comment: [readonly]="DateRelatedObject.bool_DatesEdit ? true : false" works with Angular 6+

Answer (score 5):

For angular **4+** versions you can try

```
<input [readonly]="true" type="date" name="date" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can either set [disabled]= "true" or if it is an radio button or checkbox then you can simply use disable

For radio button:

```
<md-radio-button disabled>Select color</md-radio-button>
```

For dropdown:

```
<ng-select (selected)="someFunction($event)" [disabled]="true"></ng-select>
```