# How to bind dynamic data to aria-label?

Tags: html, angular, wai-aria, uiaccessibility

I have dynamic text to bind to `aria-label` on a HTML page.
This is an Angular 2 app. I am using something like this:

```ts
aria-label="Product details for {{productDetails?.ProductName}}"
```

But I get an error:

> Can't bind to 'aria-label' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Just use `attr.` before aria-label:

`attr.aria-label="Product details for {{productDetails?.ProductName}}"`

or

`[attr.aria-label]="'Product details for ' + productDetails?.ProductName"`

Examples here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aria-label?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html&hideExplorer=1

Ps. As @Simon_Weaver mentioned, there are some components that implements its own aria-label `@Input`, like `mat-select`.

See his answer here [Angular Material mat-label accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56690162/angular-material-mat-label-accessibility/59586917#59586917)

Comment: it should be `[attr.aria-label]="productDetails?.ProductName"`

Comment: @LucaDeNardi, actually, your way is less readable and you forgot to add the static string part `Product details for...`. I've added your suggested selector for anyone who wants the best fit for their case.

Comment: @BrunoJoão sorry, I meant that you should not use `[attr.aria-label]` and `{{productDetails}}` together, since the square brackets already resolve variables. You either write your attribute without square brackets **and** with curly brackets, **or** your attribute with square brackets **and** without curly ones.

Comment: @LucaDeNardi thanks for letting me know. I've removed the brackets.

Comment: @BrunoJoão the ideal way is to use square brackets.

Comment: if anyone is wondering, works for labelledby as well: `[attr.aria-labelledby]`

Answer (score 7):

You should use square brackets (`[ ]`) around the target property:

```
[attr.aria-label]="'Product details for' + productDetails?.ProductName"
```

Answer (score 4):

Also this could be further checked if ProductName in productDetails is null or undefined as

```
[attr.aria-label]="(typeof productDetails.ProductName !== 'undefined') ? 
'Product details for ' + productDetails.ProductName : '' "
```

So that the JAWS/NVDA/Narrator could able to read if it's value is present or not..

Answer (score -2):

this works for me
without `[]`.

`attr.aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink{{ i }}"`