# Translate pipe fails within aria-label in Angular Material Design

Tags: angular, angular-material2, translate

Maybe a trivial question but I've not been able to find any answer googling around.

In my Angular 5 app I've HTML like this:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" class="submit-button" aria-label="{{'REGISTER.CREATE' | translate}}"
        [disabled]="registerForm.invalid">
    {{'REGISTER.CREATE' | translate}}
</button>
```

which produces the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'aria-label' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. ("             </div>

                <button mat-raised-button color="accent" class="submit-button" [ERROR ->]aria-label="{{'REGISTER.CREATE' | translate}}"
                        [disabled]="registerForm.inval"): ng:///Register2Module/FuseRegister2Component.html@76:79
syntaxError
```

But if I write:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" class="submit-button" aria-label="SOME DIRECT TEXT"
        [disabled]="registerForm.invalid">
    {{'REGISTER.CREATE' | translate}}
</button>
```

I have no error at all.

This is beyond my understanding. Is this a problem with angular's implementations of Google's MAT or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance

Comment: how about you remove `{{ }}` and just `'REGISTER.CREATE' | translate`

Comment: @Tin Thanks Tin but it doesn't work. The compiler doesn't complain but the output text doesn't get translated at all. It is exactly like writing SOME.DIRECT.TEXT

Comment: Hey @Raffaele I don't know if you already got the answer. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658800/how-to-bind-dynamic-data-to-aria-label. This is exactly what you want. `attr.aria-label="{{'REGISTER.CREATE' | translate}}"`

Comment: @Tin It works, thanks. If you post your comment as an answer I will mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add `attr.` like the following:

```
attr.aria-label="{{'REGISTER.CREATE' | translate}}"
```

Reference: [How to bind dynamic data to ARIA-LABEL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658800/how-to-bind-dynamic-data-to-aria-label)

Answer (score 0):

and if the value from *ngFor , you need to remove ''

```
      <mat-nav-list dir="rtl" *ngIf="(categories$ | async) as categories">
    <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let category of categories" 
     attr.aria-label="{{category.name | translate}}"
     (click)="onSidenavCloseClick()" [routerLink]="category.link"
      routerLinkActive="active">
      {{category.name | translate}}
    </a>
  </mat-nav-list>
```