# Angular Material mat-label accessibility

Tags: angular, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a mat-form-field with a text input control. I have a mat-label and I also put an aria-label attribute `attr.aria-label` on the input element directly.

Is the `mat-label` sufficient for screen readers by itself? Is the `attr.aria-label` necessary or redundant?

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
<mat-label>Username</mat-label>
<input attr.aria-label="Username" formControlName="Username" matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

The same question goes for the mat-select control.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
  <mat-label>Cars</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="Car">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let car of cars" [value]="car.name">
    {{car.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Important note about difference between `[attr.aria-label]` and `[aria-label]`:

For a button you can set a dynamic `aria-label` like this:

```
 <button [attr.aria-label]="'This is a button for ' + buttonDescription">Click me</button>
```

This won't work for all material controls since some define an `@Input('aria-label')` property, which sets the attribute internally (via @Hostbinding)

[`mat-select` is one such control](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api)

Source code:

```
@Input('aria-label')
ariaLabel: string
```

Therefore if you do try to use `[attr.]` syntax for `mat-select` it won't work because the control will actually overwrite your explicitly set attribute (since the `ariaLabel` input property to `mat-select` never gets set!).

```
<mat-select [attr.aria-label]="'This will be overwritten with undefined!'">...</mat-select>
```

Instead you must just use `aria-label` input property.

```
 <mat-select [aria-label]="'Choose your own adventure! ' + 123">...</mat-select>

 <mat-select aria-label="{{ 'Choose your own adventure - ' + 123 }}">...</mat-select>

 <mat-select aria-label="Choose your own adventure 123">...</mat-select>
```

A build will tell you if you use `[aria-label]` when you should be using `[attr.aria-label]` (because the compiler will tell you there's no such input property). So if you don't want to go seek out the API for the control you're using start with `[aria-label]`.

https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Answer (score 2):

if you are using the mat label field, you should not place an aria-label on the input element directly. In your case it's redundant.

If a floating label is specified, it will be automatically used as the **label** for the form field control. If no floating label is specified, you should label the form field control using aria-label, aria-labelledby or

[https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview][1]