# Change the aria-label for button within mat-date-picker-toggle

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility, wai-aria

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" [formControl]="date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

With this markup ... the `aria-label` for the toggle button will default to "Open Calendar" ... I have tried setting `[attr.aria-label]="'Selected date is ' + dynamicText"` on `mat-datepicker-toggle` and that does not pass to the button child element, but it does pass to the `mat-datepicker-toggle` element itself.

Comment: I could be wrong as not used Angular in years but is it not `[attr.aria-label]` to add aria labels? It isn't clear whether the label is generated in the outputted HTML from the way you phrased it. Is the problem that the `aria-label` is generated but ignored or is it that it is not generated at all?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie actually you are correct and that does pass the aria-label to the mat-datepicker-toggle element itself, but does not pass to the button child element. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: So does the outputted HTML have the aria on the container and then angular material inserts a button within it via code? If that is the case I would guess you need to write some custom function to extend it as I wouldn't imagine you have access to that via exposed parameters. Could be wrong, as i said years since used Angular. Possibly could be added post render as another solution?

Comment: Just eye-balling here. Can you try ````[attr.aria-label]="'Selected date is ' + dynamicText"```` on the ````<mat-form-field>```` ??

Answer (score 0):

To apply dynamic `aria-label` you can either use `[aria-label]` or `[attr.aria-label]`. Both of these vary for different `mat-input` types. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56690162/angular-material-mat-label-accessibility/59586917#59586917).

If you add `[attr.aria-label]` to `mat-datepicker-toggler` it will apply dynamic `aria-label` to only this tag. To add dynamic `aria-label` to the child `button` element inside it you'll have to use `typescript`.

You can do that by writing this code in the `.ts` file of your component within `ngAfterViewInit` as follows:

**datepicker-component.html**

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" [formControl]="date" />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle
    matSuffix
    [for]="picker1"
    attr.aria-label="{{ 'Selected date is ' + date.value }}"
  ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**datepicker-component.ts**

```js
date = new FormControl(moment([2017, 0, 1]));

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const matTogglerChild = document.querySelector(
      'mat-datepicker-toggle'
    )?.firstElementChild;
    const ariaLabelText = 'Selected Date is ' + moment(this.date.value).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    matTogglerChild?.setAttribute('aria-label', ariaLabelText);
}
```

So, in this above code, I get the immediate child of `mat-datepicker-toggler` and then assign it a new aria-label. You can do the same for the other elements inside the `mat-datepicker`. I've implemented this inside `ngAfterViewInit` because the view doesn't get rendered in `ngOnInit`, so it'll return `undefined`.

I hope this helps you. Let me know if you need any more clarifications.

Comment: I don't think you need the attr.aria-label on the mat-datepicker-toggle :)

Comment: Is there any alternative for it or will it work as is? @RamjiSeetharaman