# Angular: Form fields read-only mode

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I have some forms that should be editable only by some users. Other users should only be able to view it.

Currently, for each form control in a form, I'm checking condition and displaying either a form control or a text. Something like,

```
<div>
    <input type="text" *ngIf="editable">
    <p *ngIf="!editable">{{value}}</p>
</div>
```

This doesn't seem to be an elegant way. Please suggest a cleaner way to achieve this, like doing something at the top level.

Comment: Why can't you make 2 different views (readonly and editable) rather than toggling each control separately?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using Angular, it is better to use [FormControls](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) and [FormGroups](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup). Take a look at [this](https://angular.io/guide/forms) guide.
Using the FormControl API you can [enable](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#enable) and [disable](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable) the input programmatically.

An other way is to use [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-) and do something like this:

```
<div>
   <input type="text" [readonly]="!editable">
</div>
```

Comment: No. I don't wanna use `readonly` or `disabled` attribute. I want to show a static element instead of a form control like `select` or `input`, but without toggling each control individually.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you mean. If you style your input to look like a "static" element?

Comment: Angular doesn't encourage binding to `disabled` elements. I can't use `readonly` as my forms have `select` element and `readonly` doesn't have any effect on them. Moreover, I primarily don't want to toggle each element individually.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should take a look to the [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive.
This should do the trick here!

Comment: Your link is for Angular 1.x and the questions source is Angular 2+.

Comment: My bad srry. The answer was given here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159827/is-there-any-alternative-for-ng-disabled-in-angular2