# Disable button during form submit

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to disable button form during submit when the form is send to the server. So far this is the solution that I found:

```
clear() {
    this.count++

    this.formGroup.get('name').reset(null);
     ..........
    if (this.count === 2) {
        this.count = 1;
        document.querySelector('.create-btn').setAttribute('disabled', '');
    }

    }

    isDisabled() {
    document.querySelector('.create-btn').removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

HTML code:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="submit()" >
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="errorClasses('name')">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control name" formControlName="name" (click)="isDisabled()">
        <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback" *ngIf="controlHasErrors('name')">
            {{controlValidateMessage('name')}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block"
                    [ngClass]="{'btn-success': formGroup.get('enabled').value, 'btn-light': !formGroup.get('enabled').value}"
                    (click)="selectTnx('enabled')">
                        <i class="fa fa-check mr-2"*ngIf="formGroup.get('enabled').value"></i>Enabled
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is there some other way to disable the submit button when the form is submitted?

Comment: I think that this question has answers that may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159827/is-there-any-alternative-for-ng-disabled-in-angular2

Answer (score 0):

If you want some kind of complex styling your ok. If you need something more simple. try something like this::

```
HTML
<input [disabled]="sendDisabled" type="button" value="Send">
...
Angular-js-class
sendDisabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just set button to `disabled`.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block" [disabled] ="btnDisabled"
[ngClass]="{'btn-success': formGroup.get('enabled').value, 'btn-light': !formGroup.get('enabled').value}"
(click)="selectTnx('enabled')"><i class="fa fa-check mr-2"
*ngIf="formGroup.get('enabled').value"></i>Enabled</button>
```

Now on Click of Button, you can simply set `btnDisabled = true` in your component. This will set button as disabled and apply appropriate styles to it.