# Enable/Disable Link/Button with [routerLink] based on Router Config data

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following route configuration:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'secure', component: SecureInformationComponent, data: { permission: 'view_secure_information'}
  }
]
```

Is it possible that every element which is using the routerLink directive is going to be disabled/enabled whether the user has the permission 'view_secure_information'? Such as:

```
<a [routerLink]="['secure']">Go to secure area of the application</a>
```

The only possible solution which came to my mind is to implement a CanActivate guard which does the check based on data within the route. 
But I also have to add on every [routerLink] attached anchor or button which navigates to this secure route another directive which does the same check and disables/enables the element such as:

```
<a [routerLink]=['secure']" *hasPermission="view_secure_information">Go to secure area of the application</a>
```

Although this works I would have redundant code and the checks are quite decentralized.

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431188/angular-2-disable-routerlink

Comment: `RouterLink` is not a very complicated directive. You can just copy the source and add your permissions functionality to your custom `myRouterLink` directive and use this one instead.