# Angular2 - Disable RouterLink

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want a better way to write these lines of code.

```
<li *ngIf="params.page > 1" class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link" [routerLink]="[]" [queryParams]="changePage(params,1)">First</a>
 </li>
<li *ngIf="!(params.page > 1)" class="page-item disabled">
     <a class="page-link">First</a>
</li>
```

I want to disable routerLink when !(params.page > 1). The class "disabled" is the easy way (ngClass). But the routerLink will be still active

Comment: regarding `params` from your template, what is the source? Did you obtained them from the `ActivatedRoute#params.subscribe()` or from `ActivatedRoute#snapshot.params`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2, disable routerLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431188/angular-2-disable-routerlink)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<li class="page-item">
<a class="page-link" [class.disabled]="(params.page > 1) ? true : null" 
    [routerLink]="[]" [queryParams]="changePage(params,1)">First</a>
</li>
```

**Edit**

I missed this part. :D

You also need to add class

```
 a.disabled {
     pointer-events: none;
     cursor:default;
 }
```

Try this and check whether it works or not.

Comment: As I say, the class is the easy part. I want to disable routerLink.