# Conditionally disable router link in Angular

Tags: angular, router

I have a number of link in an Angular project (using Angular 2), similar to:

```
<a [routerLink]="..."
     [routerLinkActive]="..."
     [routerLinkActiveOptions]="...">
    Link
</a>
```

I would like to disable some of these depending on the context/state (by changing the color and preventing the action from happening).

---

For styling, I have added to the link:

```
[class.disabled]="!isValidLink()"
```

---

This lets me show the links as disabled, but I still need to prevent the routing. If I add a `target="_self"` to the element, it prevents routing, but I need to do this conditionally, depending on some state.

Is there any supported routing way of doing this, or some other implementation that would work?

---

**Edit:** Setting `pointer-events` to none in css would prevent clicking on the link, but am looking for a solution which would prevent keyboard events from triggering it too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2, disable routerLink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431188/angular-2-disable-routerlink)

Comment: Thanks, I am having the same issue; wondering if there is a way to prevent keyboard events too? 

That question has accepted an event which disables pointer-events, but tab-entering still triggers the link - would prefer this to not happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a try like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="..."
    [class.disabled]="!isValidLink()" 
    (keydown.enter)="isValidLink()">Link</a>
```

Comment: +1 This does prevent the routing on keyboard enter key press, in addition to the styling and mouse event prevention through css.

Comment: Yeah, it's not well documented in the [oficial site](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html), but here's a [post](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3088-native-key-combination-event-binding-support-in-angular-2-beta-17.htm) about it

Answer (score 19):

Another way to disable routerLink - **replace `onClick` method**.

To do this you have to create directive:

```js
import { Directive, Input, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterLink, RouterLinkWithHref } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
    selector: '[routerLink][disableLink]'
})
export class DisableLinkDirective {

    @Input() disableLink: boolean;

    constructor(
        // Inject routerLink
        @Optional() routerLink: RouterLink,
        @Optional() routerLinkWithHref: RouterLinkWithHref
    ) {

        const link =  routerLink || routerLinkWithHref;

        // Save original method
        const onClick = link.onClick;

        // Replace method
        link.onClick = (...args) => {
            if (this.disableLink) {
                return routerLinkWithHref? false: true;
            } else {
                return onClick.apply(link, args);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Usage:

```html
<a routerLink="/search" [disableLink]="!isLogged">Search</a>
```

Comment: Searched far and wide for a solution that isn't a workaround but actually deactivates the routerLink conditionally. This is it. Works beautifully, and very simple to use.

Comment: Still works in Angular 9. This should already be a default attribute for the router. Also, this thould be the accepted answer imo.

Comment: @MartinSchneider try to use tabindex="-1" for disabled links

Comment: Very handy solution for scenarios when you only want expansion(not navigation) by clicking parent menu, and still using benefits of routerLinkActive. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

Could you do two anchor tags?

```
<a *ngIf="onCase" [routerLink]="..."
     [routerLinkActive]="..."
     [routerLinkActiveOptions]="...">
    Link
</a>
<a *ngIf="offcase" [class.disabled]="!isValidLink()">
    Link
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, this would indeed work. I am wondering if there is a way of doing it in the existing element, so I don't need to maintain two elements for every link?

Comment: Then check out the link that elvin posted for you.

Comment: It is a potentially workable solution, but would like to prevent keyboard events in addition to mouse events if possible.

Answer (score -2):

See
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057837/prevent-routerlink-action-in-angular-2/48383575#48383575). It uses a span element to capture click event and "preventDefault" with stopPropagation on span.
... It Works fine!

```
<a routerLink="/test"><span (click)="testClick($event)">Test link</span></a>
```

```
function testClick($event: MouseEvent) {
    if (expression) {
        $event.stopPropagation();
        // do something
        return;
    }
    // navigates to /test
}
```

Comment: If you are doing this that way you can probably still acticvate the link with the keyboard shortcuts. Also please show a quick code example it can help the user understand better what you are saying.