# Prevent routerLink action in Angular 2

Tags: angular2-routing, angular4-router

I have a link:

```
<a routerLink="/test" (click)="testClick($event)">Test link </a>
```

I wanted to do in `testClick` function something like this:

```
testClick(event:any) {
    if (..some expression..) {
        //custom popup confirmation
        //if true --> event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        // go to link
    }
}
```

But calling `preventDefault` doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: instead of event.preventDefault, pls try return false;

Comment: @VeenaK.Suresh doesn't work (

Comment: do you really need routerLink="/test" in your anchor (<a>) tag? if  u can remove it from there and add the routing in your testClick() else statement, i hope then it will work.

Comment: @VeenaK.Suresh unfortunately I do, because I need to have a possibility to open this link in new tab, but if a link doesn't have a routerLink attribute, a browser doesn't "parse" it as a link.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any solution?

Comment: @Timtest, I've written custom routerLink directive. For me it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to stop router navigation based on some condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808818/is-it-possible-to-stop-router-navigation-based-on-some-condition)

Answer (score 13):

You can wrap your link's text with span element and bind event handler on this span:

```
<a routerLink="/test"><span (click)="testClick($event)">Test link</span></a>
```

And your handler:

```
function testClick($event: MouseEvent) {
    if (expression) {
        $event.stopPropagation();
        // do something
        return;
    }
    // navigates to /test
}
```

Comment: `$event.preventDefault()` should be shown in your handler too

Comment: `span` does not have any default handler of click event, so you have not  to prevent it.

Comment: you are right, but in this case you have to prevent, or it will not work as expected @VitaliyAlekask

Comment: Working solution. In case you are using Material Buttons, take care of the click area. You have to remove the padding of the anchor element and set it to the inner span element + "display block" (for height)

Comment: With that solution using the keyboard to trigger a link may still works

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue for this on github: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21457

In the meantime, you can help yourself with putting some more logic into the routerLink directive:

```
<a [routerLink]="someExpression ? [] : '/test'" (click)="testClick()">Test link</a>
```

This way you need to handle your expression twice: once in the link and once in the code; but on the other hand you don't have to care about the event at all, since it will propagate normally but the router will simply ignore it.

Comment: this is the only solution that actually worked, and i searched allot, thank you!