# Test a disabled anchor does not change current location when clicked

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a component that is a simple *disabled* anchor with a router link

```js
@Component({
    template: `<a [routerLink]="target" disabled>click me</a>`,
})
class DisabledLinkComponent {
    target = '/destination';
}
```

I want to test that the location **does not change** when clicking the anchor, using `RouterTestingModule`.

```js
@Component({ template: '' })
class FakeComponent {}

describe('DisabledLinkComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{ path: 'destination', component: FakeComponent }])],
            declarations: [DisabledLinkComponent, FakeComponent],
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    it('should not change location when clicked', () => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DisabledLinkComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();

        fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('a').click();

        expect(TestBed.get(Location).path()).not.toBe('/destination');
    });
});
```

But the expectation fails. What is wrong in the way I test?

Comment: The test is right, that doesn't work. [*"Using `disabled` with an anchor tag (an `<a>` link) will have no effect."*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess the best option here is to set the routerLink to `null` if you want the anchor to have no effect when clicked.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

@Component({
    template: `
        <a [routerLink]="disabled ? null : target">click me</a>
    `,
})
class LinkComponent {
    target = '/destination';
    disabled = true;
}

@Component({ template: '' })
class FakeComponent {}

describe('DisabledLinkComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{ path: 'destination', component: FakeComponent }])],
            declarations: [LinkComponent, FakeComponent],
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    it('should not change location when disabled and clicked', async () => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LinkComponent);
        fixture.componentInstance.disabled = true;
        fixture.detectChanges();

        fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('a').click();
        await fixture.whenStable();

        expect(TestBed.get(Location).path()).not.toBe('/destination');
    });

    it('should change location when not disabled and clicked', async () => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LinkComponent);
        fixture.componentInstance.disabled = false;
        fixture.detectChanges();

        fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('a').click();
        await fixture.whenStable();

        expect(TestBed.get(Location).path()).toBe('/destination');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) is right, your disabled attribute doesn't work as expected.

Check out [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35431405/3508174) as a correct way of disabling an anchor.

For proper Location.path() assessment though, you need to wrap it with whenStable:

```
fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
  expect(TestBed.get(Location).path()).not.toBe('/destination');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the `whenStable` advice. Still, I'd prefer to use it with `async`/`await`